# When to use event.Skip() in wxPython event handlers?

Tags: python, events, wxpython, wxwidgets

In wxPython you often see that in event handlers after doing stuff, `event.Skip()` is called, which - in my understanding - prevents the event handling from stopping at this point but let it rather propagate to the next event handler, if there is any.

```
def onButton(event):
    # Doing stuff after button is clicked
    event.Skip()
```

What I don't understand is: Is it (always) necessary to call `event.Skip()`? Or only in specific cases? Or is it more or less good practice to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably, this is all about event propagation (but only for wx.CommandEvents, as only they propagate), so unless you have a specific need to call `event.Skip()`, you shouldn't call it, as a matter of course. To do so, simply means that you are executing more code than you need to.
http://wiki.wxpython.org/EventPropagation

Comment: One case where you definitely have to do ``event.Skip()`` is in the handler when binding to ``wx.EVT_CLOSE``. If you don't, the closing/destruction of the frame will never happen/not happen properly.

Comment: @nepix32 Not if you use `destroy()`

Answer (score 1):

> Is it (always) necessary to call event.Skip()?

It is definitely not always necessary. The [documentation](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Event.html#wx.Event.Skip) explains `event.Skip()` very well. Calling `event.Skip()` is not about good or bad practice. It is about event handling machinery.

Most of the time, people don't need `event.Skip()`. YMMV.